# Does this opetation and structure have a name?

Tags: abstract-algebra, self-learning

A is a commutative ring ,a is an ideal of A.
then we can get a structure A/a called quotient ring by operation of quotient.

question is :if we have a ring A/a and a set a .
How to get A?

This operation we use like a inverse quotient.
How to call the operation that we use A/a and a to get A.

Is there a name for A?

Comment: If you're only looking at $A/a$ (and pretending we have no knowledge of $A$), then $a$ is not really well-defined (it is zero in $A/a$).

Comment: The question is not well-defined as currently stated. However, what you seem to be looking for are extensions of $A/a$ by $a$. Viewing these only as abelian groups, the extensions are given by $\text{Ext}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}(a, A/a)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the ring $\mathbb{Z}/ 4 \mathbb{Z}$ and the ring $(\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z})^2$. Both give $\mathbb{Z}/ 2 \mathbb{Z}$ when you take the quotient by $\mathbb{Z}/ 2 \mathbb{Z}$. Thus, in general, $A$ is not uniquely defined.